# Natural language interface to database using python

Tags: python, sql, database, nlp

I am working on a project related to natural language process using python. In my project, I have my database and some data related to finance and I have to create my own page and if I give a question for example `what is the net income of apple?` then I have to transfer my question into a query like `select net_income from finance where name = apple` and get the answer to my question.

I've completed tokenizing the given question and removed stop words from it. I am unable to convert the tokens and add them into the query. I am very thankful if anyone could help me by giving your ideas?

Comment: Well... For starters, you need some mapping between "net income" to a column name. Maybe synonyms like total income, sum of income could also be given? The column won't match as closely... Also what's determining what table you're querying from? You'll need another mapping for that information. Then, "of apple" could be "for Apple". Basically you need to detect the parts of speech, not just get tokens

Comment: Yeah..But I thought of starting from very basic questions by just giving the direct names which I've mentioned in my database if I am able to write the code for inserting the words into the query then later I can improvise my code by adding the parts of speech and synonyms,etc.

Comment: How you have stored tokenized version of `what is the net income of apple?` You may need to make POS-analysis too, as mentioned above.

Comment: By splitting my question into tokens and I removed stop words from my question and got the useful words such as what, net income, apple.

Comment: Just removing stop words, you may have `net, income, apple`... Okay, so what do you do with those tokens? Select them? Sum the income for some column containing Apple as text? In other words, how does "net" get associated to "income"? What other columns do you need to consider? For example, do you have the stock ticker with the data? Perhaps parsing "net financial income of company named Apple" would be easier to parse the needed tokens

Comment: Okay so..After tokenizing the question what will be the next step i.e., how to insert those words in the query and how do I maintain the format ?

Comment: https://github.com/machinalis/quepy

Answer (score 1):

Introduction

Natural Language Interfaces for Data Bases.

What if you could ask the question on your mind in the language of your choice and we add additional computational work within the system to automatically convert it into a SQL-like format to retrieve the results? Think of this as a hyper-intelligent ChatBot that converses with you seamlessly — without obstructing your thought flow with errors and other bugs.

Techniques for converting NL to SQL
The broader category of techniques

- Semantic parsing
- Neural Network Models

Methods available in the literature

- Pattern Matching Systems
- Syntax-based Systems
- Semantic Grammar Systems
- Intermediate representation languages:
- Seq2Seq models
  Key Challenges
- Input request in natural language
- Type of database
- Parsing system to convert natural language

Libraries

- https://github.com/FerreroJeremy/ln2sql
- https://github.com/dadashkarimi/seq2sql
- https://github.com/xiaojunxu/SQLNet
- https://github.com/ryanzhumich/editsql
- https://github.com/taoyds/sparc

References

- http://www.iaees.org/publications/journals/selforganizology/articles/2016-3(3)/algorithm-to-transform-natural-language-into-SQL-queries.pdf